# Rotating an image around alternate axis

Tags: android

I am attempting to rotate an image of about 200 by 20 pixels a bit like a car speedo needle, I can get it to rotate around its center point correctly with the code below but i need to to rotate around a lower axis not the center. From looking around changing
    *mat.postRotate(angle);*
to something along the lines of *mat.postRotate(angle,30,10)*; should change the axis around which it rotates but it does not it still rotates around its center. What do I need to set?
Thanks

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.needle);
bMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 200, 20, true);
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(angle);
Bitmap bMapRotate = Bitmap.createBitmap(bMap, 0, 0, bMap.getWidth(), bMap.getHeight(), mat, true);
image.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
```

Comment: post two images,  before and after transformation

Comment: don't rotate the line, rotate the endpoint as it moves around the dial's outer perimeter, then you just draw a line from that movable point to the fix center point of the needle.

Comment: Did you try to translate to the point you want to rotate about? `mat.setTranslate(30, 10)` Then `mat.postRotate(angle)`